# Cómo importar datos de un Excel a DataGrid pero iniciarlo en la segunda fila?

Tags: c#, sql-server, postgresql

Disculpen una duda, como cargar de excel un formato iniciando en la segunda fila? tengo este código solamente que el excel esta justificado en la primera fila y ahí surge la necesidad de comenzar en la segunda, alguna idea por favor?

```
introducir el código aquí //Boton que pie el requerimiento de excel 
    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog OFD = new OpenFileDialog();
        OFD.Filter = "Excel |*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";
        OFD.InitialDirectory = "Desktop";
        if (OFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Ruta = OFD.FileName;
            txtRutaAlmacen.Text = Ruta;
        }
        txtRutaAlmacen.Text = OFD.FileName;
        DGVAlmacen.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill; //se ajustan las
        //columnas al ancho del DataGridview para que no quede espacio en blanco (opcional)
        string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Ruta + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""";
        string query = "SELECT ROW_NUMBER(2) NoPARTE, DESCRIPCION, TOTAL FROM [Hoja1$]";
        //Creamos el provider
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        //Lo abrimos
        excelConnection.Open();
        //Creamos un Data Adapter que extraiga los datos necesarios(todos) del provider
        OleDbDataAdapter data = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, excelConnection);
        //Creamos una tabla

        DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
        //Usando el Data Adapter que tiene los datos seleccionados, rellenamos la tabla.
        if (dTable == null)
        {

        }
        data.Fill(dTable);
        // Conectamos el BindingSource con la Tabla.
        DBSource.DataSource = dTable;
        // Conectamos el DataGridView con el BindingSource
        DGVAlmacen.DataSource = DBSource;
        txtIdAlmacen.Text = "";
        cmbbxSem.SelectedIndex = -1;
        txtNumParteAlm.Text = "";
        txtNomParteAlm.Text = "";
        txtCantidadAlm.Text = "";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Indica en esta linea de código:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Ruta + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;""";
```

La opción `HDR` = `NO`:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Ruta + @";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;""";
```

Eso hace que el encabezado del excel no se cargue.

Comment: Excepción no controlada del tipo 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en System.Data.dll

Información adicional: No se han especificado valores para algunos de los parámetros requeridos.



Hola, gracias por tu tiempo, sigue mandando error debido a que no encuentra parámetros en la consulta

Comment: En ese caso tu mismo me estas diciendo cual es el problema, no puedo ayudarte más pues no sé en que momento da ese error, ni tampoco como esta conformado el excel. Pero, según veo lo que deseas es cargar un archivo excel a un DataGrid, en ese caso te aconsejo usar la librería `EPPlus` [http://epplus.codeplex.com/]

Answer (score 1):

Después de pensarlo un poco encontré una solución, debido a que se necesitaban ciertos valores con algunas formulas, utilice el nombre de la segunda hoja (Hoja2) y dentro de ella mande a llamar los datos necesarios realizando la  misma consulta pero ya con los parametros especificos de lo que necesito, se bloqueo la hoja y automáticamente al usuario capturar los valores en la hoja principal me arroja lo requerido, de igual manera gracias!